# How to build database API with Django that connects bridge to local server?

Tags: django, database, web-development-server

I want to implement a website that serves as an API to a database on one of our servers. The server is secure and can only be accessed on site. So to push data from the server, a bridge computer must be used. I want to set up a site where users can request access, filter a database, and then retrieve files based on their filtering criteria. For example, if a user wants all files for a subject aged 50 years, then a command needs to be executed on the host machine connected to the correct network to retrieve those files (based on an identifier) from the secure server, then send to the user, perhaps after performing a couple of additional operations on the host machine (python and bash scripts). I want to build all of this in python (Django) and mysql (if necessary). Would a set up like this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's really simple actually.

Use Django to create your database, follow the tutorials but before deployment change the settings to use MySql instead of postgresql or sqlite (which is the default). I personally find that django rest framework helps to ease the process.

If you already have a database, then just connect to it instead of using django orm, you can use the mysql package for python to perform raw queries inside django views, you don't have to use the django models at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I didn’t realize that connecting to the files was done through MySQL as opposed to Django. So when is the additional processing of the files implemented?

Comment: @B.Williamson You could upload your files to the database as Blob. If you don't want to do that then the static content server of django might be for you.

Comment: interesting. So it’s possible to connect the static files to the database? For example, if 1 subject’s files passed filtering criteria, then the static file (and related subfolders and files) could be connected to their database entry so the interface would know which files to grab? I have looked for hours for resources on building something like this with no luck. So if you have any resources, I am happy to read those. Thanks for your help.